# Como puedo hacer que el canvas no afecte a los demas elementos de la pantalla¿?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Estoy haciendo un juego de ahorcado y para ello estoy usando canvas, pero cuando lo coloco me mueve todas las otras imagenes que tengo, entonces quiero que se posicione por detras o por delante de las imagenes sin que se mueva lo otro. Asi se ve la pagina sin canvas: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi se ve con canvas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces como se ve las dos imagenes de la muerte se mueven hacia abajo y la imagen que se agrega de la horca tambien, cuando lo que yo quiero que haga es que se pongan encima del canvas y despues agregarle mas cosas al mismo.

El codigo es este:

```js
function iniciarJuego(){
        document.getElementById("iniciar").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("agregar").style.display = "none";
        crearPantalla()


        var palabra = sortearPalabra();
        crearLineasPalabra(palabra.length)

        


        

}   
function crearPantalla(){
    var pantalla = document.querySelector("canvas")
    var pincel = pantalla.getContext("2d");
    var horca =new Image();
    horca.src = "../images/horca.png"
    horca.style.width = "250px"
    horca.style.height = "250px"
    horca.style.position = "relative"
    horca.style.top = "25px"
    horca.style.left = "245px"
    document.querySelector("main").appendChild(horca)
    

}

function sortearPalabra(){
    const palabras = ["palabra", "comida", "perro", "gato", "animal", "richard"]
    var aleatorio = palabras[Math.floor(Math.random() * palabras.length)]
    return aleatorio
}

function crearLineasPalabra(palabra){

    var pantalla = document.querySelector("canvas")
    var pincel = pantalla.getContext("2d");

    pincel.fillStyle="black";

    pincel.moveTo(500,20);
    pincel.lineTo(900, 20)
    pincel.stroke();
    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Koulen&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
        <title>Ahorcado</title>
    </head>


    <body>
        <header>
            <img id="imgLogo" src="../images/Vector.png" alt="logo">
            <h1 id="titulo">AHORCADO</h1>
        </header>


        <main>
            <canvas width="1200" height="800"></canvas>
            <div>
                <img id="muerte1" src="../images/muerte.png" alt="">
                <img id="muerte2" src="../images/muerte.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div>
                <button id="iniciar" onclick="iniciarJuego()">Iniciar Juego</button>
                <button id="agregar">Agregar Palabra</button>
            </div>
            


        </main>


        <footer>
            Desarrollado por 
        </footer>


        <script src="../js/main.js"></script>

    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Una opción es pintar las imágenes en el canvas en vez de usar elementos distintos.

Comment: creo que va a terminar siendo lo mas sencillo, gracias